# Variable size image with max width/height inside a fitted centered element

Tags: html, css, image, vertical-alignment

I have a `<a>` tag with an `<img>` inside of it that I want to be vertically and horizontally on the screen, but also have a max-height and max-width so that if sits nicely on the screen with whitespace around it. It needs to work for both portrait and landscape images on any screen size and cannot crop the image at all. I can't get the image's max-height to work, however.

The `<a>` also has some text that is positioned under the left side of the image, so I'm trying to make the size of the `<a>` match the size of the `<img>` to make the positioning of this text right.

HTML:

```
<a href="#">
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="it's a picture">
    <p>Image Title</p>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 60%;
    max-height: 60%;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

p {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Can you show as an example(like an image), how it should look like?

Comment: @passatgt here are examples for both portrait and landscape. I've added a red border to represent the max width and height for any image. http://imgur.com/a/r550u

Comment: CSS-tricks has a [tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/) on how to do this: http://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/

Answer (score 2):

Setting percentage max-width when no width specified is almost the same as setting a regular percentage width, so i changed the link size to simple width/height 60%, hope thats all right. Now, the easiest way to center things is Flexbox. You can learn more about it here:

http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/

I had to add an extra div to wrap both the image and subtitle, so the text can be aligned to the bottom left of the image.

```
<a>
    <div>
        <img src="image.jpg"/>
        <span>asd</span>
    </div>
</a>
```

And here comes the flexbox CSS:

```
body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

a {
    display: block;
    width: 60%;
    height: 60%;
    border:2px solid red;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

a span {
    display:block;
}

a div {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;   
}

a img {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    display:block;
}
```

And this is how it looks like:

http://jsfiddle.net/9xgyu6a4/

Works with portrait images too:

http://jsfiddle.net/9xgyu6a4/1/

Comment: Flexbox could be a good solution. I'll give this a try. However, it is not working for portrait images for me. The image height is still extending past the red border: http://imgur.com/AoZEbdh

Is there any way to fix this and have the height be limited by the bottom of the `<a>` container?

Comment: Works fine for me in Safari / Chrome. What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome (just checked and it is up to date) on Yosemite.  Firefox is a fail as well. It is working on Safari, however.

Answer (score 0):

[This code from CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/) will allow you to center the image almost directly in the middle of the screen:

```
<a href="#">
    <img src="/pathTo/image.jpg" alt="it's a picture">
    <span class="title">The Image's Title</span>
</a>

a {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.title {
    position:fixed;
    width:327px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

The trick is to use fixed positioning on the `<a>` element, such that both the top and left CSS properties are taken into account.  The image won't resize as the viewport becomes smaller, and will stay centered in landscape/portrait layouts.  Assuming that the height and width of the image is known (in this case, the image is 327px by 327px - I'm not sure exactly what is meant by "variable size image"), `.title` has an equal width to the image.

Comment: The problem is that the size of the image is not known because this code is being used in a content management system where the user will be uploading images and the image in this layout will always be changing. I need to find a solution that will work regardless of the image and screen size of the viewer. The problem isn't so much getting the title to line up, it's getting the image to fluidly fit on the screen.

Comment: Ah, yeah. I just saw the image included the comment that you posted that shows the behavior you want - can you post more code so that what you show in the image could be replicated?  Also, is the issue just that the picture cuts off at the top?  Would adding padding to the `img` work?

Comment: What happens is the image expands to 100% of the `<a>`, which is 60% of the total width, but the image is much taller than it is wide so it get's pushed off the bottom of the screen. It's ignoring the max-height. What code would you like to see? That `<a>` is just sitting in a `<body>` with the height set to 100% and there's not much else there.

Comment: @Alex I just threw the code you posted into a text editor and the positioning was a little weird; it didn't match up with the image you posted.  In any case this is beyond my expertise and passatgt's answer is better.

Comment: the image I posted was created in photoshop as a rough example of what I am trying to get the image to do. I don't think it would have matched up with my code.

Comment: Ah right on - thought it was a screenshot.  I should have drank more coffee this morning.  Sorry!